# MySql: Simple Problem with Creating Tables & Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1005

I have problems with creating tables & foreign key. (errno:150) 
here is a screenshot Updated Image: http://img264.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=14866_db_122_223lo.jpg

Maybe the problem is the database design.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`projekt_user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`projekt_user` (
  `UserID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`projekt_auswahl`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`projekt_auswahl` (
  `UserID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `projekt_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `projekt_kategorie_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `projekt_attachment` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`, `projekt_id`, `projekt_kategorie_id`) ,
  INDEX `UserID` (`UserID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `UserID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`UserID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`projekt_user` (`UserID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`projekt_kategorien`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`projekt_kategorien` (
  `projekt_kategorie_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `kategorie` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projekt_kategorie_id`) ,
  INDEX `projekt_kategorie_id` (`projekt_kategorie_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `projekt_kategorie_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`projekt_kategorie_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`projekt_auswahl` (`projekt_kategorie_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`projekte`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `projekte` (
  `projekt_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `projektname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `projekt_status` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projekt_id`) ,
  INDEX `projekt_id` (`projekt_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `projekt_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`projekt_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`projekt_auswahl` (`projekt_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: The requested URL /aAfkjfp01fo1i-16490/loc901/14094_db_122_901lo.jpg was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your foreign keys in the wrong direction, and need to load the tables in order (parents before children):

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`projekt_user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`projekt_user` (
  `UserID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`projekt_kategorien`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`projekt_kategorien` (
  `projekt_kategorie_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `kategorie` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projekt_kategorie_id`) ,
  INDEX `projekt_kategorie_id` (`projekt_kategorie_id` ASC) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`projekte`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `projekte` (
  `projekt_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `projektname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `projekt_status` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projekt_id`) ,
  INDEX `projekt_id` (`projekt_id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`projekt_auswahl`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projekt_auswahl` (
  `UserID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `projekt_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `projekt_kategorie_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `projekt_attachment` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`, `projekt_id`, `projekt_kategorie_id`) ,
  INDEX `UserID` (`UserID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `UserID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`UserID` )
    REFERENCES `projekt_user` (`UserID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `projekt_kategorie_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`projekt_kategorie_id` )
    REFERENCES `projekt_kategorien` (`projekt_kategorie_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `projekt_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`projekt_id` )
    REFERENCES `projekte` (`projekt_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Had I paid more attention to the ERD you provided, I'd have seen that the "crows feet" were pointing upwards, when the convention is they always point down (or the left if necessary).

Comment: @elmanino: Thank you -- very easy to diagnose with the scripts you provided.